# Chosing a suitable switch mode power supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I have an application where I have to drive 40 high-power LED's in short pulses using a LED light controller. I got the part after the light controller dimensioned, so now I just need to choose a suitable PSU to supply the light controller. The PSU output voltage has to be in the range of 35-48Vdc and be able to supply around 550W of power within 20us.

I found a couple of 48Vdc 600W PSU's that will meet the first two requirements, but what parameter should I look after to be sure that the PSU can deliver the needed power within just 20us?

**Clarification:**
A single pulse starts with a 20us delay (low), then there is a 300us period where the pulse is high followed by a 19700us delay (low). My main concern is to make sure that the PSU can deliver the power needed immediately after the initial 20us delay.

Comment: How about posting some datasheets?

Comment: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/319845.pdf or http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1301934.pdf or http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/93443.pdf are examples of PSU's I have looked at.

Comment: What is the average power you need? In other words, what is the time delay between pulses?

Comment: @SzymonBęczkowski The pulse width is 300us and the delay is 19700us, so the average power is only around 8W.

Comment: Depending on your wire length, you may need a local reservoir anyway, or the inductance will kill your pulse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$ 550W \times 300 \mu s = 165mJ \$ (energy per pulse)

\$ 165mJ \times 50/s = 8.25W \$ (average power, 20ms pulse period so 50 pulses per second)

35–48Vdc range needed so use a 48V 10W PSU and a bank of capacitors for storing energy. Caps will slowly charge up to \$ V_{max} = 48V \$ and during the pulse, they will be discharged down to \$ V_{min} = 35V \$. Energy needed in caps \$ \Delta Ε = 165mJ\$. The caps will give this energy while discharged from \$V_{max}\$ to \$V_{min}\$:

\$ \DeltaΕ = C\dfrac{(V_{max})^2}{2} − C\dfrac{(V_{min})^2}{2} \$

solve for C

\$C = 2 \Delta Ε((V_{max})^2−(V_{min})^2) = 300 \mu F \$

(330μF closest cap value)

If you use a bigger cap, the voltage will be more stable, plus a cap this size costs almost nothing. Remember to get one with at least 63V rating.

Comment: See my clarification.

Comment: Where do you get the 50s from in your average power computation?

Comment: From your answer it seems like my problem is not solved by choosing a specific PSU but rather by adding a charge reservoir to the circuit - this I would like to avoid. A PSU must have some sort of internal reservoir; otherwise a cap would always be needed, correct? If yes, is there a PSU parameter that describes the size of this charge reservoir?

Comment: I doubt a 22 \$\mu\$F/63 V electrolytic will have an ESR and ESL low enough to get 1 A/\$\mu\$s rise times from. An X7R will do better on ESR, but I don't know about ESL. And they're expensive.

Comment: @stevenvh You are right, but I think it is enough to add a small film cap in parallel with electrolytic just to give the initial current.

Comment: @mola I corrected the calculation for the pulse length you have given. I doubt that the companies selling PSUs will give you the output capacitance value. There is alwayse some capacitance, but just to be sure you can add your own. Adding a 330μF cap is not a big problem.